# Sorting methods in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Is there an easy way to sort methods within a class in Eclipse?

Comment: Why would you want to sort the methods?

Comment: I've got a couple of versions of the class to merge; this will make merging more straightforward, because some methods wound up at different places and diff doesn't resolve them nicely.

Comment: By name is sufficient, but by protection, static-ness, and name is probably better.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> select the class, Source > Sort
>   Members
>
> you can set the order in Java
>   preferences

via [Eclipe forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20100218080217/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg02539.html)

Comment: Sometimes this gives compilation error.Say if one variable is instantiated based on the other and it on sort the variable goes above.
I was wondering if this can be handled in any way

Comment: @Ravisha I usually handle this by hacking the variable name to force alphabetic order OR simply by not using sort members on that file...

Answer (score 17):

Found it on the Eclipse [newsgroup](https://web.archive.org/web/20100218080217/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg02539.html):

> select the class, Source > Sort
>   Members

Comment: This answer was actually added one minute earlier than the selected one.

Comment: First isn't always best, and generally it's better to have an answer from someone other than the OP.  The accepted answer also includes some useful information about settings which my answer here is missing.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed you were the OP. I understand now your decision.