# Are there any Java method ordering conventions?

Tags: java, methods, conventions

I've got a large-ish class (40 or so methods) that is part of a package I will be submitting as course-work. Currently, the methods are pretty jumbled up in terms of utility public/private etc. and I want to order them in a sensible way. Is there a standard way of doing this? E.g. normally fields are listed before methods, the constructor(s) are listed before other methods, and getters/setters last; what about the remaining methods?

Comment: Also note that when _working_ with code like this, most IDE's allow you to see the definition of whatever is underneath the cursor automatically.  This mean you do not have to do anything but glance.

Comment: If you have 40 methods in a single class - you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Some conventions list all the public methods first, and then all the private ones - that means it's easy to separate the API from the implementation, even when there's no interface involved, if you see what I mean.

Another idea is to group related methods together - this makes it easier to spot seams where you could split your existing large class into several smaller, more targeted ones.

Comment: +1.  I prefer to sort by visibility.  Shame Eclipse cannot do this automatically (it will always group all constructors together and all methods together.)

Comment: @finnw, file a bug report.  Stranger things have been known to be implemented from there.

Comment: You should never write classes that huge in the first place to ever follow the second option.

Comment: @Ben: My experience is that any "never" will have exceptions.

Comment: @JonSkeet in a few cases, where ordering conventions are no longer relevant, test classes for example. Not to write bad code is better advise than how to arrange bad code.

Comment: @Ben: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I've written code where there are very naturally many members, without violating any separation of concerns etc.

Comment: Agree with Jon Skeet.  Just take a look at the Java library collection classes which have a significant number of methods and fields.

Answer (score 161):

1. Class (static) variables: First the public class variables, then the
   protected, and then the private.
2. Instance variables: First public, then protected, and then private.
3. Constructors
4. Methods: These methods should be grouped by functionality rather
   than by scope or accessibility. For example, a private class method
   can be in between two public instance methods. The goal is to make
   reading and understanding the code easier.

Source: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html

Comment: This is 15 year old and probably a little outdated with the appearance of modern IDEs...

Comment: @assylias: IMO, readability is independent of IDE. Keeping public before private is usually better.

Comment: This is 9(2021-2012) years old and probably its gold now.

Comment: what is the ordering convention when we have static variables, static blocks, static methods, constructors, instance variables and instance methods ?

Answer (score 48):

The more precise link to «Code Conventions»: [«Class and Interface Declarations»](https://web.archive.org/web/20130516014426/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852)

Comment: +1, afaik - this is the ONLY post that actually answers the question.  YES there is a standard order as dictated by Oracle and Sun: 1. public comment, 2. class, 3. internal comment, 4. static data, 5. instance data, 6. ctors, 7. methods, and within each section group logically, not by accessibility.

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk «Internet Archive» was down…

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: non-archived working link also in [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427127/1357094)

Comment: or in short: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html :)

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if there is universally accepted standard but my own preferences are;

- constructors first
- static methods next, if there is a main method, always before other static methods
- non static methods next, usually in order of the significance of the method followed by any methods that it calls. This means that public methods that call other class methods appear towards the top and private methods that call no other methods usually end up towards the bottom
- standard methods like `toString`, `equals` and `hashcode` next
- getters and setters have a special place reserved right at the bottom of the class

Comment: I really prefer constructors last because a properly written constructor should do very little other than assign its arguments to properties.

Comment: @GordonM Why do you think so? I would go as far as to argue the reverse is true. You should always think of the cleanest API for your classes. And that is often not the way they are stored in, so I often do quite a bit of processing to relief the caller from this burden

Comment: @GordonM I am not talking about side effects. So no changes to lists that were passed or anything alike. Just passing and setting values requires that the Class tells you a lot about it's implementation, which should not be the case

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Am not quite sure what you're saying here, but it looks like you're saying the constructor should do a lot of setup work other than assigning its arguments to internal state.  This is most definitely wrong, because it means things are happening by "magic".  A call to ```new Thing()``` should only result in a new Thing being instantiated.  It should not result in database connections being opened, files being written, etc etc.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Having dependencies in a constructor doesn't tell you anything about the class's implementation other than what its dependencies are.  This is a good thing, not a bad one.

Comment: I like ctor first too. When using dependency injection this seems useful as it puts dependencies at the top -- context info for a class; easing me into what the class is by what it uses. Further, languages are starting to provide this sort of thing in the class declaration which is at the top ... Kotlin does this.

Answer (score 14):

40 methods in a single class is a bit much.

Would it make sense to move some of the functionality into other - suitably named - classes?  Then it is much easier to make sense of.

When you have fewer, it is much easier to list them in a natural reading order.  A frequent paradigm is to list things either *before* or *after* you need them , in the order you need them.

This usually means that `main()` goes on top or on bottom.

Comment: youre so right - this is not an ordering issue

Comment: You don't always have a choice, for example if you are implementing an interface with a lot of methods.

Comment: This is an Android Activity, so there are lots that simply can't go anywhere else, `onPause()`, `onResume()` etc., as well as all of my `OnClickListener` fields, which, although they are fields, don't look or behave like them so it's sensible to list them separately.

Comment: @finnw, abstract classes are nice and usable for this purpose.

Answer (score 12):

My "convention": static before instance, public before private, constructor before methods, but main method at the bottom (if present).

Comment: For code that is well factored code this is a good approach. I tend to put consuming code above consumed which leads to public before private.

Answer (score 2):

Also, eclipse offers the possibility to sort class members for you, if you for some reason mixed them up:

Open your class file, the go to "Source" in the main menu and select "Sort Members".

taken from here: [Sorting methods in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854232/sorting-methods-in-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse? If so I would stick with the default member sort order, because that is likely to be most familiar to whoever reads your code (although it is not my favourite sort order.)