# What's the convention for the sorting of the members?

Tags: android, conventions

I found and read the Android code style conventions here:

[click me](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

but I didn't find the conventions for the sorting of the members. Alphabetically? By visibility? something else?

I mean the members that sort Eclipse when you click source ---> sort members, that are:

[image: members to sort]

less these:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you consider to be a member?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4668276/905349).