# Eclipse Sort Members uses wrong order

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

Eclipse always places static methods before static fields even though the order in Member Sort Order says static fields before static methods. Has anyone encountered and solved this issue?

Comment: What a shame!!! You haven't asked a question though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any Java method ordering conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4668218/2982225)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion It's not a duplicate...

Comment: Do you mean the order from Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Members Sort Order is different than the order from Ctrl + O ?