# Java code order for abstract classes

Tags: java, coding-style

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668218/are-there-any-java-method-ordering-conventions) and I am wondering where would abstract methods fit in for an abstract class.

Any convention known for this?

Comment: I've always seen them treated just as any other method, whatever the grouping convention used.

Comment: I put them at the beginning of the visibility block they belong to, because I see them as kind of interface methods for the subclasses.

Comment: i believe (might be wrong) there is no such convention (in the sense of standard) regarding method sorting. The 2 main approaches related to that, that i know about, are about "grouping based on functionality" or "based on visibility" (public, protected, private etc). I have not seen any specific regarding abstract so i guess the 2 other main approaches remain. In my case, but that's me, i follow visibility approach (same as it is stated for class members) and put abstract method the last of their "visibility group".

Comment: @JBNizet Hmm, okay... Somehow the OCD side of me is telling me that mixing abstract with non-abstract methods is messy.

Comment: That question was "closed as too broad", so perhaps this should be also? Personally, I just put methods close by to where they are used, and stick to small classes.