# Automatically Format and Arrange Declarations and Definition in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting methods in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854232/sorting-methods-in-eclipse)

When I format java code in eclipse using ctrl + shift + F. it does the formating but does not put together the pieces of code together. For example, I often mix up the variable declaration and functions one after other. Also forget to specify where to insert the getters and setters when generating source code. I want to all my final static variables first followed by member variables followed by getter setters and followed by other methods. Example:
**Unfomated code :**

```
static final var1;
int var2;
void func1(){}
int var3;
void setVar3(){}
static final var4;
void func2(){}
int var5;
void setVar1(){}
int getVar3(){};
```

**Formated Code :**

```
static final var1;
static final var4;
int var2;
int var3;
int var5;
void setVar1(){}
void setVar3(){} 
int getVar3(){}
void func1(){}
void func2(){}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/854257/437226

Comment: I believe this question may be a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/854232/437226

Make sure you do some research before asking a question--it may have been answered before.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask