# can eclipse arrange my methods in alphabetical order?

Tags: eclipse

It would be nice to have my methods put in alphabetical order, just like the java docs.
Can eclipse do that for me ? Or do i do it manually ?

Comment: Quest Exists in this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549319/eclipse-organize-methods-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting methods in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854232/sorting-methods-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can view class members in alphabetical order in the Outline view, but I don't think you can sort them alphabetically.  You can only sort them by type (e.g. initializers, constructors, etc) and visibility (public, private, ...).

Comment: I will have to wait till my reputation = 125.

Comment: Eclipse may not do what you want it to do, but I have answered your question. That doesn't mean my answer deserves to be marked down. My information is the same as what is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549319/eclipse-organize-methods-in-alphabetical-order?lq=1

Comment: It's different information than given in the answer there. Plus if the question is a dupe it should be marked as such and closed, no?

Comment: My answer and the other answer describe the same thing, but in a different way.  I have no problem if this is marked as a duplicate.